# Find similarity of two ranked lists that have weights

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, ranking, similarities

Suppose I have two lists with columns `rank`, `app_name`, `weight` that look like this:

```
list1:
[(1, "app1", 0.6), (2, "app3", 0.2), (3, "app4", 0.1), (4, "app2", 0.1)]

list2:
[(1, "app3", 0.4), (2, "app5", 0.3), (3, "app2", 0.2), (4, "app6", 0.1)]
```

and I want to compare how similar the app rankings are between two lists are. Which similarity formulas can I use that take into account **both** the `rank` as well as the `weight`?

Note that the `weight` is different across different lists. Also note that lists may contain different `app_name`.

I've seen many formulas that just compare the strict ordering of apps, like Jaccard similarity, RBO, Kendall Tau, etc. I've also seen weighted Jaccard similarity that assumes that the weight is the same for a given `app_name`. But I can't discover any similarity metric that takes into account both the `rank` as well as different `weight`.